# Can I connect a dehumidifier pump to the AC condensate access point in my attic?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, drain, dehumidifier

I recently bought a dehumidifier with built in pump for my attic. There is an HVAC unit in the attic with a condensate drain pan and drainage pipe. There is (what I think is) an open access point in the pipe, and I'd like to run the dehumidifier's pump tube into this access point. Is this kosher? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Photo here: https://ibb.co/1fBfVKT

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but the risk is that if the condensate drain gets clogged then you're pumping water into your air handler.  The vent is there for a reason, so don't hard-connect to it, it needs to be functional.  Just run a smaller diameter tube to it.

Comment: Thanks! So if the drain gets clogged then the water starts flowing towards the HVAC, which is presumably bad. Is there a "correct" way to do this, given my setup? Here's a 0:09 second video of the entire pipe: https://www.veed.io/view/8d4bd27b-afbd-43fa-a9b6-3aadb0c46b1b/showcase